# Hosting a Windows service

Tags: service, azure, amazon-web-services, hosting

I'd like to host a Windows service application using e.g. Azure on AWS. I know I can modify my application to be an Azure worker role. Can I do the same thing with AWS or is there a better hosting provider. My application uses a database preferably SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is an IaaS - Infrastructure as a service, you can very much take a Windows Server 2008 R2 - EC2 instance and treat it as your own laptop or computer or server(just take RD) and deploy your windows service.

Regarding the DB, you can install SQL Server or MySql in the same instance (if you are fine with performance) or put the DB server in a separate EC2 instance. If you are worried about adding more EC2 instances, RDS is also an option available.

Answer (score 0):

Since the AWS AMI (Amazon Machine Image) is a standard Windows 2008 operating system (various editions) you can create and deploy a Windows service as you normally would - and in the .NET world, Windows Service is still the way to go. Azure worker roles only work in Windows Azure.

With SQL Server on AWS you can use an AMI with SQL on already or install your own (see the [pricing options](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/) for windows/SQL instances) but you will not have failover functionality as you can only have express or standard. To have redundant SQL servers you would need to do something like database mirroring or replication and keep it running yourself. There is no database service for SQL on AWS like there is with RDS (mySQL and Oracle) or SQL Azure